# How does google.com detect I'm in Firefox when already using Chrome's user agent

Tags: javascript, websites

It's well known that google.com doesn't show the microphone search icon in Firefox, probably to incentivize people to use their web browser. (They give it on youtube.com, which is weird for being inconsistent). I thought that setting the user agent in Firefox to the latest Chrome's user agent (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36) would be enough, but now, instead of not showing the microphone icon, it weirdly flickers, as in the video here https://youtu.be/UpYh20YVIh4

Why does this happen? I tried to understand what javascript is causing that, but I failed as I have no experience debugging web apps on Firefox.

I don't know what causes this, either Firefox or client side js?